# Keycloak getting empty login page i.e., without username and password form

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Recently I migrated the keycloak database by volume mounting the data into a different environment. Till then it worked fine and suddenly I am getting the empty login page (Username and password form is not getting displayed). In the theme, I commented the 'if loop' i.e., 8th line on this file https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/login.ftl#L8, and it's working. Why should I need to comment the line? what is **realm.password** means? Any idea?

While migrating data, is there anything busted? If so, which table in the keycloakdb should I need to check to fix this issue.

Feel free to ask me If you need more information.

[image: Keycloak Login Page]

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should share more information about your setup like which db you are using, how is keycloak installed, keycloak versions.

But with the given information:

`realm.password` means just the password of the realm and if you don't have this set up usually means that you have to set it up. Usually it can also happen if you install Keycloak from scratch and not yet added a password.

You can do this by running the `bin/add-user-keycloak.sh` in the `JBOSS_HOME` directory.

Btw, you shouldn't change the password directly in the db or do changes directly there.

Comment: Thanks for the Information. I will update the description with more info. Sorry about that.

BTW, what is the use of realm.password? Why do we need to create a user to set a realm password? (Generally while creating a realm from the keycloak admin portal UI, we don't create a realm password explicitly right? Just curious to know how exactly this is getting created in a clean keycloak setup and where it is getting used?)

Comment: as I already said, when you start keycloak you have the master realm and for that you need a user and a password (realm.password). Usually if you start that from docker you will give a parameter for the password or if you do it from installation zip/tar you need to use the `add-user-keycloak.sh` script.